# CodeIgniter variable available throughout my application?

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to setup a variable for Global use in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313174/best-way-to-setup-a-variable-for-global-use-in-codeigniter)

I have meta data about the user that will constantly change therefore I dont want to store it a session.

It would also need to be available throughout my application.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Sean Jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to try using codeigniter's MY_Controller:

[Codeigniter | MY Controller](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Controller_-_how_to_extend_the_CI_Controller)

```
class  MY_Controller  extends  Controller  {

    public $var;

    function MY_Controller ()  {

        parent::Controller();

        $this->var = 'hello!';

        }
    }
```

This is placed in the 'core' folder called MY_Controller.php. You would then call

```
class Whatever extends MY_Controller {}
```

MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller in all of your controllers.

You can then call

```
$this->var;
```

From anywhere within your application.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I've just read your other question. I guess this solution is not what you're looking for.

You can store it in a library (for example, `mylib`) and add this library to autoload in application/config/autoload.php:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('mylib');`

Then you can load this library and access the variable anywhere in your application:

`$this->load->library('mylib');`

`echo $this->mylib->my_variable;`